# What is wrong with this array, only getting error message 'array'

Tags: php, arrays

What is wrong with my array, Im getting error message 'array', which doesn't say much what is wrong with it. I can't see what is wrong with it, it not uploading the picture to the intended folder, just hoping someone can help me out please.

```
<?php

$s = "-";

 $sqlName=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM business WHERE email='$login_bus' LIMIT 1")or die   
 ("Sorry we have a mysql error!");

 $row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlName);$busID=$row["id"];$busName=$row["businessName"];   


 $upload_path = ''.$busName.'/productServiceImage/';

 $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "JPG", "PNG", "JPEG");
 if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST");
 {
 $name = $_FILES['pro_serImage']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['pro_serImage']['size'];

 if(strlen($name))
 {
 list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
 if(in_array($ext, $valid_formats))
 {
 if($size<(1024*1024)) // Image size max 1 MB
{
$actual_image_name = time().$s.$busID.".".$ext;

$tmp = $_FILES['pro_serImage']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $upload_path.$actual_image_name))
{
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize(''.$upload_path.$actual_image_name.'');

mysql_query("UPDATE product_service SET image='$actual_image_name',  
image_width='$width', image_height='$height' WHERE businessEmail='$login_bus' LIMIT  
1")or die ("Sorry we have a mysql error!");

echo "<img src='/".$upload_path.$actual_image_name."'>";
}
else
echo "failed! ".error_get_last()."";
}
else
echo "Image file size max 1 MB!"; 
}
else
echo "Invalid file format!"; 
}
else
echo "Please select image!";
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please only paste the relevant parts of the code? People are usually reluctant to read so much code. Thanks.

Comment: If you use  mysql_query()  functions, your code can be SQL Injection exploited aka hacked.

Comment: There's no array in this code, also it's not formatted at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
echo "failed! ".error_get_last()."";
```

to

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you echo an array, it will show up 'Array'. I don't if it's you issue, but you should use var_dump() of print_r() instead of echo. These will show you the content of the array.